# Game was fun for a year but suddenly is not?

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players, roleplaying, social, player-characters

So this may be a long story but my group and I have been playing “The Curse of Strahd” for a little over a year. It has been a really amazing and wonderful time. Everyone got a long so well and the characters had a good dynamic.

Then something happened. I am not sure what is was but a couple of months ago I realized that they would all talk over me or dismiss anything my character had to say. It hurt my feelings and I brought it up. They told me they were not doing this, so I let it be.

A few weeks later one of the party members basically said my character was being mean to theirs and I should change my character. My character was upset with theirs for a little bit cause they recklessly blew my character up with a bomb. Their claim was that my character was too sensitive (they tease him a lot, it’s not that much fun) and that I should change my character to fit the party more.

Why did this suddenly change? They liked my character before and now they don’t? How do I fix this without changing my character? (Also my character apologized to this players character but they have started to treat me and my character like I don’t exist.)

Comment: Welcome to the stack MooneCircle! I recommend checking out the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a good grip of how this website works, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have more questions.

Comment: Some of the other info that could be useful would be: age of the people in the group and your social relations with them (ie how you know each other outside of the game and how you are treated then).

Comment: While answers here will try their best to give you a helpful answer, this does feel like the sort of situation where some back and forth discussion might help solve your real issue. For that we have a [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/48759) better suited to that kind of discussion. Which includes our own [chat]. If you want more help that the answers here can provide I encourage you to check it out. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Do you interact with this group regularly outside of the campaign?  If so, has anything changed recently outside of it? If this is a social issue, and it sounds like it might be, then the reason for it might not be contained within the game itself.

Comment: Let’s see players are all late 20s to late 30s. Two of them are my good irl friends (DM and play who’s character was mad at mine) and two of them are random new people we invited to the group via a discord server. The. The one other is a friend of the DM that I did not know previously. We recently had a dnd get away weekend and everyone was cool and chill. We had fun. I interact with them only on discord outside of the game because we don’t live near one another.

Comment: @MooneCircle It’s best to add details like that to the question, so they are prominent to anyone reading (and perhaps answering) the question. Also, one of the crucial questions was about how they treat you outside of game, whether that’s on Discord or whatever. I see weekend went well (that was in person?), but what about the rest of the time?

Comment: It was in person, everyone was really nice. Discord usually I get answered but it’s hard to tell tone. Everyone now and then they will over look something I’ve said. But it’s just text.

Answer (score 12):

### This is a social problem, not a D&D problem.

While sometimes people can misunderstand how d&d works and do things at the table that annoy others due to that misunderstanding, this does not read like one of those situations.

Likely you are either missing social cues, misreading the situation, or perceiving that others are viewing you negatively when they aren't.  These are all common social problems, and as D&D is a social game, they affect it.  There are rarer causes for this kind of situation, like a personal animosity with someone with more social clout leading to bandwagoning against you, etc.

However the answer to the problem is unlikely to be found in any character actions, roleplaying techniques, or likewise.  It's probably more to do with how you present yourself at the table.  If you change how you portray your character in a way that pleases and excites people, that might make a difference, especially if D&D is the main reason you are interacting with this group.  But overall, figuring out the social cause or situation which is leading to you observing this freezing-out and negative feedback is likely to be easier in terms of getting back to enjoying the game.

Comment: Downvoting because of the default assumption that this is the OP's fault.  ("It's probably more to do with how you present yourself at the table.")  I've seen enough situations where a player or character are singled out for reasons largely beyond their control to make me very apprehensive about this assumption.  (It seems you've seen those situations, too-- I'm just much more nervous about the relative weights you assign.)

Comment: I am confused about how user2753 answered the question. You say I should change my character but that it’s not a character or D&D problem. You think I have upset them in some other way, then why would changing my character change anything? Please clarify.

Comment: @MooneCircle they mentioned "that ___might___ make a difference" (emphasis mine) and then stated their actual answer in the final sentence: "_But overall, figuring out the social cause or situation which is leading to you observing this freezing-out and negative feedback is likely to be easier in terms of getting back to enjoying the game_"